# reading data from firestore and save locally in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve usernames from a users collection and save in an array. I use this:

```
var usernames:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad(
    
    populateUsernames()  
}

func populateUsernames() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("users").getDocuments() { [self] (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let username = document.get("username") as! String
                usernames.append(username)
                print(usernames) //THIS PRINTS ["user1", "user2"] WHICH IS CORRECT
            }
            print(usernames) // THIS PRINTS [] WHICH IS FALSE
        }
        
    }   
}
```

Why does the array reset to [] after the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that would cause this behavior. You're either printing the wrong array or something else is overwriting it, which doesn't seem likely. I notice that you aren't referring to the array with `self` which you would need to do in this closure. Therefore, rename the array for testing purposes.

```
var usernames2: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    populateUsernames()
}

func populateUsernames() {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            for doc in snapshot.documents {
                if let username = doc.get("username") as? String {
                    self.usernames2.append(username)
                    print(username)
                } else {
                    print("username not found")
                }
            }
            
            print(self.usernames2)
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also crudely parse these documents which may not be harmful but is nonetheless unsafe, which this code addresses.